# How to focused cursor on the top line in a comment box?

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a project using codeigniter. 
There have a setting. User can save there signature. And when he/she open the comment box the signature is auto inserted and the cursor cursor will be focused on the top line.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="comment-box"><?php $signature->signature ?>
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

SQL: I'm get the signature using sql and it passing from my controller. And I get data using `(<?php $signature->signature ?>)` this.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#description").focus();
    }
);

Note: When i using this jquery, the cursor focused but it before the value. (image 1)
```

[image: Image 1:]

Here is an image. I want like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){   
       $("#comment-box").text("\n" + $("#comment-box").text());
       $("#comment-box").focus();

});
```

or, as you are using **#description** as control id

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {       
        $("#description").text("\n" + $("#description").text());
       $("#description").focus();
    }
);
```